# Phpmyadmin MySQL trigger throws error 1362

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have table `algas` in where i have columns (which i need) Worked hours, Hourly Rate and Salary.

Basicly what i need is to make trigger, when one of (Worked hours, Hourly Rate) is changed it calculates Salary.

```
Salary - column
Salaries - table name
```

I have tried numerous ways, but none works. Latest code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sum_algas AFTER INSERT ON Salaries 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`Salary` = NEW.`Hourly rate` * NEW.`Worked Hours`;
```

ERROR:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>      #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_alga_sum 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mydb.algas
        FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    algas_summa integer;
    alga_ref integer;
BEGIN
    alga_ref := NEW.`Alga`;
    algas_summa := NEW.`Nostrādātās stundas` * NEW.`Stundas likme`;
    alga_ref = algas_summa;
END;
```

ERROR:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR UPDATE ON mydb.algas FOR EACH ROW DECLARE algas_summa integer' at line 4

Comment: It would be way easier to just calculate the salary on demand - when querying the DB.

Comment: And there is no `OR` . You need 2 triggers. One for `update` and one for `insert`.

Comment: And use `before insert` instead of `after`